# Self assigned TLS sertificate traefik

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

My problem is self assigned cert instead of lets-encrypt cert 
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik
    command:
      - --api
      - --providers.docker
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/data/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - public
      - private
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`dashboard.example.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
        - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=auth"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.auth.basicauth.users=admin:admin"
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

service labels

```
- "traefik.http.routers.gitea.rule=Host(`gitea.example.com`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.gitea.entrypoints=websecure"
- "traefik.http.routers.gitea.tls=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.registry.tls.domains.main=example.com"
- "traefik.http.routers.registry.tls.domains.sans=*.example.com"
- "traefik.http.routers.gites.tls.certresolver=resolver"
- "traefik.http.services.gitea-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
```

traefik.yml:

```
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"

certificatesResolvers:
  resolver:
    acme:
      email: mail@example.com
      storage: acme.json
      tlsChallenge: {}
```

This is what I get in my Firefox:
[image: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT]

This is happend, because browser takes traefik default cert, but there is must be lets-encrypt cert 
 With log level debug I get

```
level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.80.1:53932: remote error: tls: bad certificate"
```